# WordPress - custom post type pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type (question) related to a custom taxonomy (support)

In my-theme/taxonomy.php I have this code:

```
<?php

$taxonomy = get_queried_object()->taxonomy;

if ($taxonomy == 'support')
{
    get_template_part('template/support/categories');
    exit;
}

wp_safe_redirect(site_url('/'));
exit;

?>
```

Means I target a specific template file for "support" taxonomy.

In my taxonomy template file I make a custom query:

```
<?php $current_category = get_term_by('id', get_queried_object()->term_id, 'support'); ?>

<?php $questions = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('question'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'posts_per_archive_page' => 5,
    'paged' => ((get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1),
    'nopaging' => false,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'support',
            'terms' => array($current_category->term_id)
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
)); ?>

<?php if ($questions->have_posts()): ?>
    <ul class="list normalize">
        <?php while ($questions->have_posts()) : $questions->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="nav-previous">
    <?php next_posts_link( __('Previous', 'my-theme'); ?>
</div>

<div class="nav-next">
    <?php previous_posts_link( __('Next', 'my-theme'); ?>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I have about 11 posts, page 1 shows the 5 first posts, but the problem is that no pagination is shown.

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Your code and with my taxonomy

```
<?php $questions = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('studies'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,    
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'nopaging' => false,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'studies',
            'terms' => 11
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));


?>

<div class="grid9">
<div class="entry-content">
<?php if ($questions->have_posts()): ?>
    <ul class="list normalize">
        <?php while ($questions->have_posts()) : $questions->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h3>                
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $questions ) ); 
?>
```

This works fine ,Don't forget to use wp-pagenavi plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but don't you have a 404 error page when navigating with pagination?

Comment: You Are Welcome ,No i dont get 404 error when navigating.

Comment: my god I'm getting crazy with that pagination, could not find the issue.

Comment: Try changing your page template name and check , that might be the issue .  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92194/custom-post-type-navigation-404-on-page-2

Comment: You mean /* Template Name: xxx */  ?

Comment: Yes Try changing Template Name

Comment: And also try changing your template file name

Comment: Actually I'm not using template name, I'm including a template file (my-theme/template/support/categories.php) with get_template_part(); in taxonomy.php as shown in my code above. Maybe is it the problem?

Comment: Hope that causes the problem , Add taxonomy-support.php it will directly call the taxonomy with name "support"

Comment: @ManoharSingh you should actually update your original answer if you want to edit it

Comment: @ManoharSingh the problem is the same, really strange, I'm not using any plugins and I have no filters or anything that can make that issue. Mistery is there

Answer (score 3):

You can try this pagination plugin

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/
```

And add this code in your template

```
<?php if (!function_exists('wp-pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } else { ?>
    <div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code above the "endif;" and just below the end of while loop.

```
 <div class="nav-previous">
    <?php next_posts_link( __('Previous', 'my-theme'); ?>
</div>

<div class="nav-next">
    <?php previous_posts_link( __('Next', 'my-theme'); ?>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I just tried to use wp_pagenavi plugin and it works but when switching to page 2 I got a 404 <?php wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $questions)) ?>

Comment: pass the 2 parameters also, Paged and Posts per page... these two are essential for pagination..

Comment: Ok, I used $max_pages param for next_posts_link() and it shows me the pagination links but getting a 404 error when visiting page 2. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ussually this works for me:

`$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $questions->max_num_pages
) );`

Notice the question variable. :-) After you use this, go to Settings->Permalink and Save twice.

You can find a bigger tutorial [here](http://adambalee.com/how-to-add-pagination-to-your-wordpress-blog-without-a-plugin/) with the same example.